# Can I use an inspect.Signature instance as a signature for function that an ide will see?

Tags: python, typing, keyword-argument, argument-unpacking, python-inspect

Can I use an inspect.Signature instance as a signature for function that an ide will see?

I am asking because I want a way to requires specikic key value pairs, and a catch all type for unknown other keywords. Function signatures and kwargs let one do this.
But I want to do this for key value pairs defined with tuples.

For example:

```
a: int
1scarykey: str
kwargs: float
```

I am able to make my own introspect.Parameter class which allows this, but the IDE does not know the signature of the inspect.Signature that I created and what is required when calling signature.bind